# singlar/negotiate no json response - no singlar/connect

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, negotiate

I'm trying to use the SignalR library in the project that we are currently working on. I've read a few blogs, looked at a few stackoverflow answers and checked the documentation of signalr but without any luck.
The code below is only the simplest sample that I'm trying to make working.

I'm using SignalR 1.0.1 with Hubs, jquery 2.0.0, ASP.NET MVC2, .NET Framework 4,
signalr/hubs are loaded through `Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")`.
In the source code of the page, when I click signalr/hubs I can see SignalR generated js code.

I've also added `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` to the beginning of Application_Start()
My Hub:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send()
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage();
    }
}
```

Client code in jQuery document ready block

```
$(function() {
    var chat = $.connection.chat;

    chat.client.addMessage = function() {
        console.log("hello here");
    };

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.error(function() {
        console.log("An error occured1");
    });
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function() {
            alert("Now connected!");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Could not connect");
        });
});
```

The problem is that:
**`http://localhost/EC/signalr/negotiate`** returns status 200 OK, but the response body is empty, so there is no connection created.

I've tried to set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`, but did not changed anything, also tried `$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost/EC/signalr';` but again no effect.

I also kept my hubs class in Hubs folder or in root of the project.

I would appreciate any help with this, as I'm running out of ideas, how and where to look for solution.

Comment: What does the console output look like?

Answer (score 0):

@suleks ,

By any chance is your page missing the "signalr/hubs" script?

```
<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it occured that there were problems with our servers, which were blocking everything. Thanks for looking into our problem.
Question can be closed.

Comment: How did you fix it? Did you open some port or something on the server? I am facing the same issue, I get no response from signalr/connect or signalr/reconnect , I suspect that is causing some clients production to disconnect and never reconnect unless tried manually.